# fallbackTag doesn't work and code throws NoPactsFoundException

Tags: pact, pact-jvm

I am using 4.1.11 version of junit5 provider.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>au.com.dius.pact.provider</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit5</artifactId>
  <version>4.1.11</version>
</dependency>
```

As per the documentation, I am specifying both tag and fallbackTag in my provider test class.

```
consumerVersionSelectors = {
                @VersionSelector(tag = "branch123", fallbackTag = "master")
        }
```

Now its supposed to use master tag contract if branch123 tag contract doesn't exist. However it doesn't work me and throws following error:

```
au.com.dius.pact.provider.junitsupport.loader.NoPactsFoundException: No Pact files were found to verify
```

I can confirm that master tag does exist from pact broker as well as using that in tag field and running the test successfully.

Is this a bug in library? Or am I missing anything?

Looking at code of VersionSelector, it seems that does have fallbackTag() method, however when I go into PactBroker, consumerVersionSelectors() method doesn't seem to have any reference of fallbackTag:

https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-jvm/blob/4_1_11/provider/src/main/java/au/com/dius/pact/provider/junitsupport/loader/VersionSelector.java

https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-jvm/blob/4_1_11/provider/src/main/java/au/com/dius/pact/provider/junitsupport/loader/PactBroker.java

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks and sounds like a bug - could you please raise it on the Pact JVM issues register?